# Linking EFI application with LLVM on MacOS

Tags: c, clang, llvm, uefi

I'm attempting to cross-compile and link a very simple EFI application that is using the [EFI headers from the Zircon kernel](https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/fuchsia/+/refs/heads/main/zircon/kernel/lib/efi/include/efi). Despite my best efforts, I am unable to link a working PE executable under macOS Montery (with apple silicon), due to the LLD flag `-subsystem:efi_application` not being valid. The full error is:

> ```
> FAILED: test.efi: && /opt/local/bin/clang -target x86_64-none-elf -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fuse-ld=lld -dll -WX -Wl,-subsystem:efi_application -Wl,entry:efi_main src/main.c.obj -o test.efi   && :
> ld.lld: error: unknown argument '-subsystem:efi_application'
> ```

[Several](https://dvdhrm.github.io/2019/01/31/goodbye-gnuefi/) [guides](https://github.com/yoppeh/efi-clang/blob/master/makefile) indicate that `lld-link` is required to compile this correctly, however adding `-fuse-ld=lld-link` results in errors stating:

> ```
> clang: error: invalid linker name in argument '-fuse-ld=lld-link'
> ```

This occurs **despite the fact that I have `lld-link` in my `$PATH`**. If I, instead, pass the full `lld-link` path to `-fuse-ld=`, I get the following error:

> ```
> FAILED: test.efi: && /opt/local/bin/clang -target x86_64-none-elf -ffreestanding -target x86_64-none-elf -nostdlib -dll -WX -Wl,-subsystem:efi_application -Wl,-entry:efi_main -fuse-ld=/opt/local/bin/lld-link src/main.c.obj -o test.efi   && :
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '--eh-frame-hdr'
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '-m'
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '-dynamic-linker'
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '-o'
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '-L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-13/bin/../lib'
> lld-link: warning: ignoring unknown argument '-L/usr/lib'
> lld-link: error: could not open 'elf_x86_64': No such file or directory
> lld-link: error: could not open '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': No such file or directory
> lld-link: error: could not open 'test.efi': No such file or directory
> lld-link: error: src/main.c.obj: unknown file type
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

I am using the MacPorts [LLVM-13](https://ports.macports.org/port/llvm-13/) package. The result of `$ lld-link --version` is `LLD 13.0.0`.

---

For reference, the code I'm attempting to compile and link is, simply:

```c
#include "efi/protocol/graphics-output.h"
#include "efi/protocol/loaded-image.h"
#include "efi/system-table.h"
#include "efi/types.h"

#define ERR(x) if (EFI_ERROR((x))) { return (x); }

efi_status efi_main(efi_handle handle __attribute__((unused)), efi_system_table* st) {
  efi_status status;

  /* clear the screen */
  status = st->ConOut->ClearScreen(st->ConOut);
  ERR(status);

  /* print 'Hello World' */
  status = st->ConOut->OutputString(st->ConOut, u"Hello World");
  ERR(status);

  return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

What do I need to change above in order to build an EFI application using LLVM on macOS?

I'd also be curious to know any ideas as to why `-fuse-ld=lld-link` would fail when it exists in my `PATH`, and why using `-fuse-ld=/opt/local/bin/lld-link` would result in other implicit linker flags not succeeding.

---

**System Details:**

- **Compiler Suite:** LLVM-13 (Macport Installation)
- **Host OS:** macOS Monterey (Apple Silicon, M1 Pro)
- **Target Arch:** x86_64
- **Build System:** CMake using custom toolchain (which passes the `-nostdlib`, `-target ...` args, etc.)

Comment: Did you try this on default `arm64` terminal or rosetta2's `x86_64` terminal? If not, I think you should try this on rosetta2. If not installed, install via `softwareupdate --install-rosetta`. Then type `arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh` or `arch -x86_64 /bin/bash` to enter `x86_64` zsh or bash terminal. (There are several different ways to enter rosetta2 terminal, you can search) Also, anytime you can type just `arch` command to see which arch running on your terminal `arm64` or `i386`. Just a little advice but maybe helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `clang-cl` to compile your code, using `/c` option to compile only: do not link yet. Use `/Fo` option to specify the output object file. 
The `clang-cl` offers compatibility options from MSVC `cl.exe`. For further details, run `clang-cl --help`. The build target of `clang-cl` is default to windows, so you don't have to reset the build target in order to compile for EFI applications. 
Be warned that `clang-cl` does not have full support to MSVC intrinsics. Intrinsics like `__vmx_vmptrld`, `__svm_vmload`, etc. are broken. `clang-cl` would generate a `call` instruction rather than the specific instruction. Define them in inline assembly in GCC's syntax, if you want to use these intrinsics. 
After you compiled all source files into object files, run `lld-link` to link all output object files with `/SUBSYSTEM:EFI_APPLICATION` parameter into an EFI application.

I haven't used the header files from Zircon yet, but I tried [compiling EDK II libraries with LLVM](https://github.com/Zero-Tang/EDK-II-Library) into `.lib` files on Windows. 
With the help of these `.lib` files, I made some simple EFI applications. For instance, you can check this [partition enumerator](https://github.com/MickeyMeowMeowHouse/UefiDiskAccess) out. 
The batch scripts might not work on MacOS, but, by reading them, you can definitely figure out the general ideas about how to specify the parameters. 
If you want to use EDK II by virtue of its rich libraries, you might want to install Netwide Assembler as well, in that the assembly codes in EDK II libraries are NASM.